# Filter the entries shown upon SELECT in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have entries in a certain mariadb table with values in a column named `code` like:

```
ABC-SI-GR-0
ABC-SI-NAV-0
ABC-GO-NAV-0
ABC-SI-NAV-3P
ABC-GO-GR-0
ABC-GO-GR-3P
...
```

... and so on

now I want to SELECT all entries from that table which have `SI` as a part of the string in the `code` column. I have tried

```
SELECT * WHERE code LIKE %SI% FROM [table]
```

which did not work.

> *check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near* 'WHERE code LIKE %SI% FROM [table]' *at line 1*

Can anyone point me to a more successful kind of syntax for such?

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing quotes around your `like` clause. Change your select to:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE code LIKE '%SI%'
```

Comment: Additionally, using `rlike` instead of `like` can be quicker since it is using a regex vs. globbing.  `select * where code rlike 'SI' from tablename`

Comment: Possibly but `rlike` is not multi-byte safe which could cause other issues.

Comment: thx for the pointer @Dave. adding quotes (of any type. tried "...", '...', ` ... `) result in the same error as before unfortunately. LIKE or RLIKE doesn't make adifference in that regards. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please modify your question with the exact statement you are using now and the complete error you are getting.

Comment: `SELECT *  FROM [table] WHERE code LIKE '%SI%'` works though

Comment: Oh gosh, how embarrassing, you had the from and where swapped and I missed it completely :(

Comment: no problem whatsoever. you pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: @ivanivan - `RLIKE` is slower than `LIKE` for equivalent functionality.

Comment: @Dave - if `SI` can occur in other parts of the codes, you need something slightly more complex, such as `LIKE '%-SI-%'`.